# Where is the .NET 3.5 SDK located?

Tags: .net, .net-3.5, sdk

Can anyone please provide a link to download the .NET 3.5 SDK? I checked the Microsoft site and Google, but cannot find a download link for this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The link above is good, here is a link that contains links to every Microsoft based SDK.  It is kept fairly up to date.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/dd299405.aspx

Edit 
If you are cutting edge.  Meaning wanting to start programming for features in Win 7, server 2008 r2. 
this would be a link with the latest and greatest.  at RC level. (although Win 7 is released with .net 3.5 sp1)

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=6db1f17f-5f1e-4e54-a331-c32285cdde0c&displaylang=en

In addition this link is also nice.

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack

Contains .net wrappers to most of the new features in win 7.

Comment: The first link no logner mention .net 3.5 SDK, the other two are broken/timout.

Answer (score 28):

**Update 2023:**
This is confirmed to still be valid in VS 2022 Community
[image]

In VS2017 Tools Menu >> Get Tools and Features...

Then in the VS Installer window select the "Individual Components" tab and make sure you have ".NET Framework 3.5 development tools" checked and installed

[image]

Comment: If you have `.NET Framework 3.5 development tools` installed, but still can't target anything below `.NET Framework 4.0`, the chances are high you don't have `.NET Framework 3.5` enabled in your Windows OS (the hint was found [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/csharp/comments/g5gz24/compile_an_application_using_net_framework_35_or/)), and the easiest way to enable this feature is through the command line like: `DISM /Online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:NetFx3 /All /LimitAccess /Source:d:\\sources\\sxs`. Don't forget to restart VS after that.

Answer (score 4):

Nowadays everything is downloaded from: https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/
Scroll down to *build tools for visual studio*, download the installer, select *individual components* and select what versions of dotnet you want to install. When done look for the "Development Command Prompt for VS", run and be happy.

Answer (score 0):

As of May 2021, this procedure affected my *VS Express 2013 for Desktop*

Follow this steps:

- Go [here](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/)
- Scroll down to: Tools for Visual Studio 2019, click for expand the content
- Click and download installer: Build Tools for Visual Studio 2019
- Run downloaded installer, click to *Individual components* and check the `CheckBox` *.NET Framework 3.5 development tools*
- Confirm the update
- Wait for the installation process, and then **restart** Win

Answer (score 0):

The .NET 3.5 SDK has been archived on the Wayback Machine:

http://web.archive.org/web/20101224222456/https://download.microsoft.com/download/3/B/1/3B16AAD3-C125-428B-8FA1-6D772F04F2B5/GRC1SDK_EN_DVD.iso

I don't know if it's still on the Microsoft website, but here is an archived link.
Note that it can take a while to download, since it is archive.org :)

Comment: Thanks for sharing! The file is still there and downloadable! However the installer is quite buggy, and I couldn't install .NET 3.5 SDK on a virtual Windows 8.1 (even after enabling .NET Framework 3.5) - it complains with an error like `Setup could not find the file WinSDK_amd64\WinSDK_amd64.msi at any of the specified source locations C:\Temp\Setup`, and indeed there is no such file there! :)